# _Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse) Error after deleting linked list recursively

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, visual-studio-2013, linked-list

I've successfully implemented a recursive PrintList method, so I don't understand why a recursive destructor won't work:

```
//recursively deleting nodes in a doubly linked list
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    if (Head == 0) //base case
    {
        Tail = 0; //fixing the dangling Tail pointer doesn't seem to fix the error...
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        Node* temp = Head;
        Head = Head->getNext();
        cout << "deleting " << temp->getNumber() << endl;
        delete temp;
        delete this;
    }
}
```

When debugging, I get the _Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse) Error after calling the LinkedList destructor, just before the program could finish up "nicely". This is past "return 0;" in main.cpp, and I stepped through the destructor code shown above with no problem, and indeed the destructor gave me all the correct test messages and worked as intended.

Even more frustrating was that I can't locate what caused this error: I tried to "step over" beyond the LinkedList destructor code, but I got the message from VS: "Source Not Available: Source information is missing from the debug information for this module".  I was thinking the dangling Tail pointer (which points at a random memory after the destructor executes) might be a problem, so I set "Tail=0;" before returning from the base case, but that doesn't seem to be working.

The only way I can suppress this error is by either:

1. constructing a LinkedList then simply ending the program without adding any nodes into it (no problem deleting an empty LinkedList), or
2. making my LinkedList in main dynamically allocated, and ending the program without manually deleting it (skipping the entire LinkedList destructor)

What is the problem here? Help!!

**UPDATE: My fantastic CS professor pointed out my problem:**

**"When the destructor exits and attempts the automatic deallocation of the node, it has already been destroyed by the delete this statement. 
When the delete keyword is used, it initiates the destructor and then deallocates the memory."**

So like @0x499602D2 pointed out, "delete this" was the problematic line, but it had nothing to do with whether my LinkedList was NEWed and then deleted or statically created at compile time then automatically destroyed. Essentially it was caused by the behavior of the destructor.

***The solution therefore is: changing "delete this;" to "this->~LinkedList();"***

***Only by "this->~LinkedList();" can I make recursive calls to the destructor without really "deleting" the calling object; instead it'll be destroyed when the destructor exits and does the automatic deallocation, avoiding the mistake of deleting it again.***

More details:
Here's my implementation of Node (doubly linked). It derives from a singly-linked BaseNode class:

```
//Specification file for BaseNode class
#ifndef BASENODE_H
#define BASENODE_H
#include <iostream>

class BaseNode
{
protected:
    char * name;
    int number;
    BaseNode * next;

public:
    //default constructor
    BaseNode();
    //overloaded constructor
    BaseNode(const char *, int);

    //destructor
    ~BaseNode() {
        std::cout << "name is: " << name << '\n';
        delete[] name;
    }

    //getter functions
    char * getName() const { return name; }
    int getNumber() const { return number; }
    BaseNode* getNext() { return next; }

    //setter functions
    void setNumber(int num){ number = num; };
    void setNext(BaseNode* ptr) { next = ptr; }
};
#endif

//Implementation file for BaseNode class
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
#include <cstring>
#include "BaseNode.h"


//default constructor
BaseNode::BaseNode()
{
    name = 0;
    number = 0;
    next = 0;
}

//overloaded constructor
BaseNode::BaseNode(const char * str, int num)
{
    roman = new char[strlen(str) + 1]; //set aside one more character for null terminator
    strcpy(name, str);
    number = num;
}
```

Then my Node class inherits the BaseNode class:

```
#ifndef Node_H
#define Node_H

#include "BaseNode.h" //include the base class for inheritance to work

class Node : public BaseNode
{
protected:
    Node * prev;
    Node * next;

public:
    Node() : BaseNode()
    { prev = next = 0; }

    Node(const char * namestr, int num) : BaseNode(namestr, num)
    { prev = next = 0; }

    //empty destructor; the BaseNode destructor automatically gets called from here and does the job
    ~Node() { }

    //getter functions and setter functions are all inherited from BaseNode, except that....
    //the BaseNode version of getNext and setNext won't work for our Node class

    Node* getNext() const { return next; }
    void setnext(Node* pointer) { next = pointer; }

    Node* getPrev() const { return prev; }
    void setPrev(Node* pointer) { prev = pointer; }

};
#endif
```

Comment: `delete this` is the problem. Your `LinkedList` class was not create with `new`, and thus there is no need for `delete this`.

Comment: 0x499602D2:
1. without "delete this", how do you suppose I can make recursive calls?
2. even if I create my LinkedList with new, I get the SAME ERROR when I delete it (like I said in my post, no error if I don't delete it)

Comment: @YiboYang - Please post the `Node` class.

Comment: You don't need recursion here. You need a while loop that continues to loop so long as `Head` isn't null.

Comment: @YiboYang - `while (Head != NULL) remove(Head);`  That is in essence all your code would really need to do, provided you have a "remove" function that removes a single node from the linked list.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I wish my professor would agree with you...but in this assignment I HAVE to use recursion for destructor...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: yeah it'd definitely be easier to have a standalone recursive remove function instead of a recursive destructor; but that wouldn't be challenging ;)

Comment: @YiboYang Basenode should have a virtual destructor.  Second, resursion makes no sense to me.  What if the linked list had 10,000 nodes?  Is the recursion going to be 10,000 function calls deep??

Comment: I doubt he told you to make the actual destructor recursive.